# Setup vue3 with rollup?

Tags: rollup, rollupjs, vuejs3

I want to setup a project with the beta version of vuejs3 that is available now. I would like to compile it into es modules, therefore I cannot use webpack.

Are there any seed projects/guides available that setup vue3 with rollup to emit an es module bundle.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a chance, check out vuejs/vite at https://github.com/vuejs/vite

This server allows you to build single file components. But it also uses rollup, so seeing the code may also be helpful.

the interesting bits are here https://github.com/vuejs/vite/blob/19f8358a47251b35557f4c2bdd8a3ac2b7ef96c0/src/node/build/index.ts#L179

but the important part is the vue-3 friendly rollup plugin `"rollup-plugin-vue": "^6.0.0-alpha.8"`

Answer (score 0):

I have created this seed project setup for rollup + vue3: https://github.com/gautam1168/rollup-vue-next

For step-by-step creation of this seed project see here: https://gautam1168.com/posts/rollup-vue-3/